# Visual Basic has stopped working vb6 window 10

Tags: vb6

I'm extremely new to this programming stuff and here is my problem. 
Every time I open my VB6, I open a new project and select a Standard EXE, everything works totally fine.

I can add anything to from the toolbox to the form. But this error comes out everytime double click on the object (eg. button)

[image]

Comment: The button you are double clicking on - what control is it?

Answer (score 0):

VB6 is in "It just works" state of support in Microsoft. You don't have to double click, Click once then drow the button with you mouse pressed on the form

Comment: i know how to draw the button. I will need to double click in order to go to the coding screen right ? That is when this error appear

Comment: @Szekuns, You can bypass that by opening VB6 code editor and selecting the control , then the click event on the top comboes